# react hook form - cannot set populated form value to null using setValue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a form that contains country and states, when a country is selected a list of state is shown in a drop down. I tried to set state value to null when a country is changed so the user can pick a new state.this process works fine in create mode. but in edit mode where I'm prefilling the forms with saved data, setting the state to null still shows the prefilled value. I will share a piece of my code doing this.

[image]

```
// set default values of form fields in edit mode
  const handleSetValue = (card: PaymentCard) => {
    reset({
      cardHolder: card.name,
      city: card.city ?? '',
      addressLine1: card.addressLine1 ?? '',
      addressLine2: card.addressLine2,
      postCode: card.addressZip ?? '',
      isDefault: card.isDefault,
      expiryDate: `${card.expMonth}/${card.expYear}`,
      cardNumber: `**** ${card.last4}`,
    });
    const defaultCountry = APP_COUNTRY_STATES.find(
      item => item.countryShortCode === card.country
    );
    if (defaultCountry) {
      const {countryName, countryShortCode} = defaultCountry;
      setValue('country', {value: countryShortCode, label: countryName});
      setIsInitialSetup(true);
      if (!COUNTRY_WITH_NO_STATES.includes(countryName)) {
        // show state dropdown
        setShowRegion(true);
        // set the regions of selected country
        setRegions(
          defaultCountry.regions.map(item => ({
            label: item.name,
            value: item.name,
          }))
        );
        const defaultState = defaultCountry.regions.find(
          where => where.name === card.state
        );
        if (defaultState) {
          const {name} = defaultState;
          setValue('state', {label: name, value: name}); // issue seems to be coming from here
         
        }
      } else {
        setShowRegion(false);
        setRegions([]);
      }
    }
  };

  // set form fields on open of edit modal
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCard) {
      handleSetValue(selectedCard);
    } else {
      resetFormField();
    }
  }, [selectedCard]);

// handle country changes
  const handleCountryChange = (name: string) => {
    // set state to undefined
    setValue('state', null);
    // find the country in the list of country lists
    const countryStates = APP_COUNTRY_STATES.find(
      where => where.countryName === name
    );
    if (!countryStates) {
      setShowRegion(false);
      setRegions([]);
      return;
    }
    // check if the country does not states
    if (!COUNTRY_WITH_NO_STATES.includes(countryStates.countryName)) {
      setShowRegion(true);
      // set the regions of selected country
      setRegions(
        countryStates.regions.map(item => ({
          label: item.name,
          value: item.name,
        }))
      );
    } else {
      setShowRegion(false);
      setRegions([]);
    }
  };

  // set regions for countries with regions
  useEffect(() => {
    if (countryWatch && !isInitialSetup) {
      handleCountryChange(countryWatch.label);
    } else {
      setIsInitialSetup(false);
    }
  }, [countryWatch]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to `''` instead of null.

Comment: Hi Luke, tried this and it didn't work

Comment: The problem is I was setting the setValue to null or undefined. setValue does not accept undefined. instead i set it to empty string. 
```
setValue("state", {value: '', label:'')
```
and this fixed it. Thanks @Luke